# git review error ValueError: No closing quotation

Tags: git-review

i'm reinstalled pip in python and module git-review. i was installs  python version 2.7 and 3.9

Command "git review" is worked, i don't know what's happend but now error

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\esinitsyn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\git-review.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\esinitsyn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\git_review\cmd.py", line 1714, in main
    _main()
  File "C:\Users\esinitsyn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\git_review\cmd.py", line 1690, in _main
    (status, output) = run_command_status(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\esinitsyn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\git_review\cmd.py", line 129, in run_command_status
    argv = shlex.split(str(argv[0]))
  File "c:\python27\lib\shlex.py", line 279, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "c:\python27\lib\shlex.py", line 269, in next
    token = self.get_token()
  File "c:\python27\lib\shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "c:\python27\lib\shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
    raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check the python installation and pip from terminal

`Python --version` in my case its shows Python 3.9.1

`pip --version` in my case I have pip 21.0.1 from d:\py39\lib\site-package\pip (python 3.9)

*try upgrading the pip if throw error just by*: `pip install --upgrade pip`

### Now for Git-review just Copy&Paste

`pip install git-review`

Comment: Did you have /python/script in path of system environment varibale

Comment: pip 20.2.3 from c:\users\esinitsyn\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

and i have environment varibles

Comment: Brother last option try reinstalling python 3 and git as well